# Rounded Border in .ass subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I am highlighting subtitle like this[image]

Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\t(0,500, \3c&H00FFFF&\3a&H128&)}highlighted

How to change the border so it will look rounded?

I have used \be and \bord but it looks this tag not for border radius